# What article should I use right after "the enigma of"?

Tags: articles

What article should I use right after "the enigma of"? Should it be "the enigma of the" or "the enigma of a(n)"?

> Please, look at these pictures. Can you guess what all these pictures
>   are about? Rain? Well, not only rain. Storm? Well, it's closer, but
>   still not fully there yet. What? Right - ball lightning. **The enigma
>   of** ball lightning has bothered scientists for centuries. On one
>   hand, it is known that it is nothing else than a big bunch of energy,
>   but on the other hand, it can easily change its size - from a big ball
>   by the size of a zeppelin or a hot air balloon to a small ball by the
>   size of an egg or even a marble...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question should really be about **lightning**, because that is the noun in question, and that is what determines what article (if any) you should use.  (*Ball* just functions as an adjunct here, like an adjective, so it doesn't determine the article.)

[**Lightning** is uncountable](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/lightning), so "**a** ball lightning" is definitely incorrect.

"The enigma of **the** ball lightning" is grammatically possible, but doesn't really mean the right thing.  [**The** is the *definite* article, and indicates that we're talking about some specific, known thing](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/definite-article/), so "the ball lightning" would indicate some specific occurrence of ball lightning.

But that's not what we mean; we're not talking about a specific occurrence of ball lightning, but ball lightning in general, so the best option is **no** article:

> The enigma of ball lightning

just like you had it in your original sentence.

Comment: What if it were a countable noun (but not a proper noun)? Would I for sure have to use an indefinite article then?

Comment: @brilliant If it were a countable noun, I would probably use the plural, although I am having trouble thinking of a good example.  For example, "the enigma of **diamonds**", not "the enigma of the diamond" (sounds like one specific diamond) or "the enigma of a diamond" (some general, nonspecific diamond?)